# Today is not Today

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, time

I will explain this by example:

When I ask a question at 21:00 and look in my profile 21 hours later it still says that I've asked the question today instead of yesterday.

Shouldn't this be just yesterday?

It's a minor detail but it's there.

Comment: UTC versus local time; I'm sure this is a duplicate, btw.

Comment: I will remove this then

Comment: @MmynameStackflow, Even `Yesterday is not yesterday`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of everything on the site is calculated/act on UTC Time Zone basis. StackOverflow is using all over the world with the different different time zones, so rather than maintaining personalized timezone, UTC Timezone is the best way.

Comment: Allright I understand, but isn't there a better way to do this because stackoverflow is used by almost the whole world.

Comment: Given the fact that it is used by the whole world is exactly why UTC is the appropriate method.

Comment: @MmynameStackflow: "Day" is a construct based on one's personal location on the Earth. Therefore, *everyone* has a different notion of "today". SO picks a single, specific standard, because you have to pick something. Not unsurprisingly, they pick *the standard* for international dates and times as their time standard.

Comment: @MmynameStackflow The **U** in UTC stands for universal.